# How to pass value of hidden field and number field associated with checkbox to the next page?

Tags: php, checkbox

i have a set of checkboxes and i want to pass their value of the selected checkbox onto the next page along with the value of the hidden field and number field associated with it.

and Here's my code

```
<form name="testform" method="post" action="page2.php">
<li>
<label>        
  <input type="checkbox" id="itemprice1" name="Itemprice[]" value="350" onclick="total(this.form);"/>
  <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?><p><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></p>
  <input min="0" max="5" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" onclick="total(this.form);"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="Itemname[]" value="Item A">
</label>
</li>

<li>
<label>        
  <input type="checkbox" id="itemprice2" name="Itemprice[]" value="250" onclick="total(this.form);"/>
  <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?><p><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></p>
  <input min="0" max="5" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" onclick="total(this.form);"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="Itemname[]" value="Item B">
</label>
</li>

<li>
<label>        
  <input type="checkbox" id="itemprice3" name="Itemprice[]" value="350" onclick="total(this.form);"/>
  <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?><p><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></p>
  <input min="0" max="5" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" onclick="total(this.form);"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="Itemname[]" value="Item C">
</label>
</li>
<input type="submit" name="fb" value="small" />
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass value of hidden field when a checkbox is selected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36196521/pass-value-of-hidden-field-when-a-checkbox-is-selected)

Answer (score 0):

Unchecked checkboxes do not show up in the request variables; the action script will need to know what checkboxes to expect.  Is that what you're looking for, or is there something in the JavaScript that's causing difficulty?

Comment: The basic logic that im looking for is when a checkbox is checked. it gets passed onto the next page along with the other values in the list. For example, if checkbox A gets checked, then the value of Checkbox A, Hidden Field A, and Number field A would be posted onto the second page. Does that make any sense? @ray

Comment: Sure, that makes sense.  You can use jQuery to remove values from any form elements that are not associated with the checkboxes.  Or you can use radio buttons to similar effect.  You probably want some intelligent logic on the action= web page to know which checkboxes are actionable and which are untouched.